# Spring boot application does not start

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, maven

I have a Spring Boot application which we install in some little servers for our products. It has always worked. This evening we have installed it in one of our servers and it did not start.

Every server is an image from a common image, so the OS is the same.

When we launch the .jar we are getting:

```
Oct 05, 2016 11:16:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Oct 05, 2016 11:16:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
Oct 05, 2016 11:16:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Oct 05, 2016 11:17:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Tomcat
```

This is our application.properties which regards hibernate

```
# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = parkuser
spring.datasource.password = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:3306/SMARTPARK?useSSL=false

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = false

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

In our pom.xml we have

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

        </dependency>
```

This is our StartServer.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class StartServer extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        SpringApplication.run(StartServer.class, args);

    }


    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

I cannot understand why the same jar works in a device and gives this error in another one and i cannot understand which is the error...

Comment: Does this server have the same java version of the others ? In the pom you have the mysql-connector dependency but I think it can not load that dependency so it can not determine what database to connect. Probably this behavior is due to the java version

Comment: every server is made from the same image...

Comment: is there a permission issue connecting to the database? either username/password or networking? it might not be possible to detect a few things since the connection is not working.

Comment: Did you put url and driver class name in spring.datasource section? Can you share this part of application.properties

Comment: Edited the question to add other properties

Comment: your Spring boot autoconfig the one included in your <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId> doesnt seem to find your mysql driver in the classpath (the one from your pom.xml), so it assumes that you have embedded one wich is not the case . So it throws the error. I suspect that is because you havent specify the versions is your pom. So, try my answer i posted below or just add a version to your mysql dependy

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same problem. Then after cleaning my local maven repository the application was up and running. Clean your local maven repo (due to corrupted dependency) and try again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but i would have replaced this :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  ....
</dependency>
```

With this:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
...
 </dependencies>
```

See thus example below :

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-relational-data-access</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        ....
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
           ....
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>[5,]</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

or else, just do this :

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>your version</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you able to run a simple Spring boot app in this server ? try one of the available apps here : https://spring.io/guides

Comment: or start a bounty

Answer (score 0):

If in case you miss `application.properties` file in your project, then also you would face such issue. Check it's available in your classpath.